# JavaScript - replace square brackets in a string

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have a simple string and trying to convert **[~sample]** to **@sample**. For example:

```
var string = 'Completely engineer client-based strategic [~theme] areas before cross [~media] technology';
string.replace('[~', '@');
```

I have tried above solution but it only convert the first one and the ] can not be removed.

---

now I learnt how to use /g

Comment: You should really try harder. Google is your friend. Questions here are expected to show at least one line of what you tried. [ask]

Comment: `[~sample]` to `@smaple` or to `@sample`? I'm asking just to be sure it was a typo

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes it's clearly a typo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is a bit more complicated than simply nesting `.replace` `[@` and `]`

```js
var string = 'Strategic [~theme] areas with cross [~media] technology [this is fine] ok?';

document.body.innerHTML = string.replace(/\[~([^\]]+)\]/g, '@$1');
```

The `([^\]]+)` makes sure to capture any character that is not an `]` but is delimited by `[~` and `]`, which is a better solution in any case preventing text like `[don't mess with me]` to be... messed.

The RegExp is explained in detail [here](https://regex101.com/r/eM6tK2/1)

Comment: _"'Strategic [~theme] areas with cross [~media] technology [this is fine] ok?'"_ is not string at OP ? Why include requirement that is not described at original Question at an Answer ?

Comment: @guest271314 to keep better solutions always visible here on StackOverflow.

Comment: @RokoCBuljan Yes, though string at solution is not original string at Question, nor included as description of requirement at Question. How did you determine that `[` `]` not containing `~` should be replaced, or not replaced ? There is no criteria for such an instance at Question ?

Answer (score 3):

Try this code:

```
string.replace(/(\[~)(\w+)(\])/g, function(match, p1, p2, p3) {
  // p1 = [~
  // p2 = theme / media / whateverWord
  // p3 = ]
  return '@' + p2
  // Returns @whateverWord
})
```

In the `1st` group:

- `\[` will select a `[`
- `~` will select a ~

In the `2nd` group:

- `\w` will select any alphanumeric character or an `_`
- The `+` states that the alphanumeric character must appear at least once, i.e. there must be at least `1` letter between the `[~` and `]`

In the `3rd` group:

- `\]` will select any `]`

In the function:

- `match` is not used in the output, but it contains the whole matched substring
- `p1` contains the `[~`
- `p2` contains the word between the `[~` and `]`, i.e. `theme` or `media`
- `p3` contains the `]`

The `return` statement `return`s an `@`, followed by the word between the `[~` and `]`

This will replace all `[~` with `@`

---

Here is a working example:

```js
var string = 'Completely engineer client-based strategic [~theme] areas before cross [~media] technology. Also, [this tag] [will be kept]'

document.body.innerHTML = string.replace(/(\[~)(\w+)(\])/g, function(match, p1, p2, p3) {
  return '@' + p2
})
```

---

**Edit:** Actually, you can make it simpler:

```
string.replace(/(\[~)(\w+)(\])/g, '@$2')
```

Check out the demo below:

```js
var string = 'Completely engineer client-based strategic [~theme] areas before cross [~media] technology. Also, [this tag] [will be kept]'

document.body.innerHTML = string.replace(/(\[~)(\w+)(\])/g, '@$2')
```

The `$2` contains the contents of the second capture group, and the second capture group contains the text between the `[~` and `]`. So the output is an `@`, followed by the text.

This is simpler and faster than the version above, and takes up less space

Comment: Seeing as I apparently just copied your answer, I must now upvote yours lol

Comment: wouldn't that screw up `" hello [something not a placheloder] "` ?

Comment: that doesn't consider other square brackets

Comment: Doesn't work on this string  _'[Completely] [engineer] [] client-based strategic [~theme] areas before cross [~media] technology'_

Answer (score 3):

You could use `RegExp` `/(\[~)|(\])/g`

```js
var string = 'Completely engineer client-based strategic [~theme] areas before cross [~media] technology';

var res = string.replace(/(\[~)|(\])/g, function(match, p1, p2) {
  if (p1) return "@";
  if (p2) return ""
});

document.body.textContent = res;
```

Comment: @JDB String at OP does not contain `[citation needed]` ; nor indicate what result of that portion of string should be ? Not certain why that requirement would be included at comments ?

Comment: @guest271314 - Yes, it's a vague question. It doesn't show any research effort and provides a weak description of what needs to be done. Really shouldn't be answering it, but that's your call.

Comment: @dandavis Could you describe how the `RegExp` `/\[~(\w+)\]/g` would be "better" ?, appears to match `[~theme] theme` , `[~media] media` as `match`, `p1`, `p2` respectively ?

Comment: @JDB _"Really shouldn't be answering it, but that's your call."_ fwiw, Answered primarily based on this portion of Question _"I know it is possible with regex but I do not know how."_

Comment: better as in faster to run, less mis-matching, and shorter: `str.replace(/\[~(\w+)\]/g, "@$1")`

Comment: @guest271314 That was sarcasm towards JDB, I don't really mean it.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith No worries. Believe have cast 0 "downvote" , here

Comment: @vicneanschi _"Doesn't work. It breaks other square brackets."_ Can you describe "Doesn't work" ? What do you mean by "breaks other square brackets" ?

Comment: try this string to see what I mean 
_'[Completely] [engineer] [] client-based strategic [~theme] areas before cross [~media] technology'_

Comment: @vicneanschi _"try this string to see what I mean ''[Completely] [engineer] [] client-based strategic [~theme] areas before cross [~media] technology' "_ ? That is not string at original Question . Original Question did not address other portions of string that may contain `[` or `]` characters; including or not including characters within `[` , `]`, nor what expected result should be. How did you determine that `[` `]` at `[Completely] [engineer] []` string should be replaced, or not replaced ?

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith - If every answer contains naive and potentially problematic code, then I will. It costs me rep too, so I'm not gleeful about it. Fortunately some of the later answers provided a much better approach, but the question is still vague and we'll never know what exactly the OP needed or was having trouble with. Druzion fixed his/her [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36046577/211627), and I modified my vote in response. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252747/211627

Comment: @JDB _"Druzion fixed his/her answer"_ Not certain how original string at Question has been transformed to an entirely different string at comments , Answers ? How is an Answer "fixed" by including content that is not at original Question ? How does any user that posted an Answer that contains `[]` not at OP determine what should , or should not be replaced at portion of string where `[]` is found, but not `~` ?, as OP does not provide an expected result for this case ?  For example, at `[this tag] [will be kept]` , OP does not describe what expected result should be. Why should a user guess?

Comment: The user asked that `[~text]` be transformed into `@text`, NOT that `[~` be transformed into `@`. By matching the complete text that should be transformed, it ensures that other text (which presumably should not be transformed) is left alone.

Comment: Again... an unclear question results in guessing games. But at least Druzion's answer answers the question that was asked rather than answering a similar but not quite the same question that you made up in your head.

Comment: @JDB _"The user asked that [~text] be transformed into @text, NOT that [~ be transformed into @"_ Yes, though `[~` without text and `]` following does not appear at string at original post. _"But at least Druzion's answer answers the question that was asked rather than answering a similar but not quite the same question that you made up in your head."_ ? The last portion of your comment is not correct. "made up in your head" ? No, answered actual Question, using actual string found at original Question; without adding to string or attempting to interpret what is not present at OP

Comment: @guest271314 - That doesn't matter. Replacing `[~` was not the question. Replacing `[~text]` was the question. This doesn't answer that question, it answers the first question (the one you made up and assumed was similar enough to be correct). It might work in your scenario, but that's not the question the OP asked.

Comment: @JDB According to OP only `[~` , `]` should be replaced. If original Question _did_ contain portions of string where `[text]` was included without `~` character, the comments and Answers addressing that scenario _could_ be accurate; however, `[text]` and `[]` do not appear at original Question ; nor does OP clarify what should be replaced, or not be replaced if those  portions of string are found. Again, how does any user who included `[text]` within their solution determine what should occur with those portions of string ? OP does not state to not replace or to replace those parts of string

Comment: @JDB Given that string at original Question does not contain `[this tag] [will be kept]` , nor description of what expected result should be if those string fragments were found within string; How did you determine that `[` or `]` at `[this tag] [will be kept]` should , or should not be replaced ?

Comment: I'll say it one last time, using the OP's words: the OP is "*trying to convert `[~sample]` to `@sample`*". Your answer predates the user's edit, and did not answer the original question. (Again... it was too vague). It does answer the user's updated question, but in a suboptimal and naive way. Given the user's edit (which I've just now seen), I'll remove the downvote, but Roko and Druzion's approaches answer the OP's stated requirements (even though the OP's code was attempting something slightly different).

Comment: Not that I am helping, but why so many comments! You do realize a little link appears at the bottom that will move this all to chat. Isn't 25 comments a bit of overkill?!?!

Answer (score 1):

```
"Completely engineer client-based strategic [~theme] areas before cross [~media] technology [with some] other bits.".replace(/\[~([^\]]+)\]/g,"@$1");
```

You need to qualify the tilde in the search. I'm surprised at all the crazy down voting. People are trying to be helpful here. If someone has a problem with the post and the answers, it's more helpful to explain WHY you downvote and not just go willy-nilly on the down-votes without explaining yourself.

As others have said, google is a friend. Try searching through www.regular-expressions.info for more help.

Comment: @Druzion, you covered most of the details in your answer. The main difference is that this replacement is forcing the search to be like [~value] and taking said value as a replacement after a literal @ sign. - The benefit to doing it this way instead of the way you proposed is so that the brackets are protected when the tilde isn't in play. In this proposal, "[don't change me] but [~change] me" would yield "[don't change me] but @ change me" whereas you solution would produce "[don't change me but @ change me" note that the closing bracket is missing on the test using your proposal.

Answer (score 1):

The code below uses Regexp to find all group of sequences that start with **[~** and end with **]**. It also captures the word in between.
**$1** in the second parameter of replace function references the found word.

```js
var string = 'Completely engineer client-based strategic [~theme] areas before cross [~media] technology'


document.body.innerHTML = string.replace(/\[~(\w+)\]/g, '@$1');
```

Comment: @dandavis I didn't see your comment while I was testing and posing my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/7oe5kh9L/33/

`string.replace(/\[~/g, '@').replace(/\]/g, '');`

```
var string = 'Completely engineer client-based strategic [~theme] areas before cross [~media] technology';
alert("Starting string:" +string);

var res = string.replace(/\[~/g, '@').replace(/\]/g, '');
alert("Final string: "+res)
```