# show external div on hover

Tags: javascript, css, css-selectors

i created a navigation and now i want to add a previewer to get related options.

this div isnt connected to the navigation but it needs to show up on hover. i surrendered after "hours" of researching :/

Here is my simplified code

https://codepen.io/solevita/pen/JXEOQg

```
<div class="col">
  <div class="content">lorem ipsum</div>
</div>
<div class="col">
  <div class="navigation">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">punkt</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

as already told, the div I want to show is not in the navigation (for responsive reasons).

Is it possible to handle this with pure css or is javascript necessary? I hope this is not the case - my javascript skills are not existent :D

thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't believe this is possible with pure CSS. This is quite easy with javascript though; you just set the event handler on the "trigger" element. And post *all* your code here instead of codepen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Sadly* (luckily) you **cannot** "navigate" using **CSS** **up the DOM tree**. You can only target next siblings and child elements (as you probably already know).

JavaScript can help you in this *specific* case:

```js
function showTarget(el) {

  var target = document.querySelector("[data-target='"+  el.dataset.hovershow +"']");

  el.addEventListener("mouseenter", function() {
    target.classList.add("visible");
  });

  el.addEventListener("mouseleave", function() {
    target.classList.remove("visible");
  });

}

[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("[data-hovershow]"), showTarget);
```

```css
.navigation{ position:fixed; bottom: 30px; }
.content         { display: none; }
.content.visible { display: block; }             /* "visible" class is toggled by JS */
```

```html
<div class="col">
  <div class="content" data-target="1">1 lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class="content" data-target="2">2 lorem ipsum</div>
</div>

<div class="col">
  <div class="navigation">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" data-hovershow="1">1 punkt</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-hovershow="2">2 punkt</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer was the most useful. Its great to have the option to show different divs.

Side note: the javascript has to be implemented before the body tag closes. Otherwise it doesnt work. 

When I am wrong, Roko C. Buljan, please correct this :D

Comment: @Chumminerd no you're perfectly right. If not using a `DOMContentLoaded` callback (AKA document.ready in jQuery) you need to put your `<script>` tags right before the closing `</body>`. You're welcome

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to modify any existing markup, you'd likely need to do this with JavaScript. The '+' selector will only work with elements that are on the same level in the DOM. Since the element you're using to trigger the showing of the content div is not on the same level in the DOM as the content div itself, this method will not work. If I am understanding this correctly, what you are trying to do can be accomplished with the following jQuery:

```
$('.navigation a').hover(function(e) {
  $('.content').show();
}, function(e) {
  $('.content').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a codepen with the Javascript (JQuery) version

```
$(document).ready(
  function(){
    $("#punkt").mouseover(function() {
      $('.content').css('display','block');
    });
    $("#punkt").mouseout(function() {
      $('.content').css('display','none');
    });
});
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rejdqq?editors=1111

Answer (score 1):

If you move `html` of `.content` to be adjacent sibling of `a` element

```css
.content {
  display: none;
}
.navigation ul li a:hover + .content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="col">
</div>
<div class="col">
  <div class="navigation">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">punkt</a>
        <div class="content">lorem ipsum</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: For specific reasons the content is not nested inside the UL

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan _"For specific reasons the content is not nested inside the UL"_ Well, why "downvote" possible solution ? where at another you have Question / Answer taken liberties to add additional content to solution at Answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/36046964/? Don't be a hypocrite

Comment: Id rather say a *possible* solution is to use JS, not something that cannot be done using CSS ;)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan With all due respect, your reason for "downvote" is absolutely hypocritical given your provided solution at http://stackoverflow.com/a/36046964/ ; where you added text to solution that did not appear at actual Question ? Provided a possible solution using `css` . If element is set to `display:none` , what does it matter that element is next to `a` element in `html` ?

Comment: @Chumminerd Note, you should be able to set `.content` element `position` to `absolute` , adjust  `left` , `top` properties to render `.content` in a position similar to that of child element of first `.col` `div`

Comment: I still believe your example is the only way to do it in plain CSS. Nothing to be hypo about.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure about pure css, check this out:
http://jsfiddle.net/raving/87865bq7/

```
<!-- normally this stuff would be on the html element -->
<!--[if lt IE 7]>  <div class="ie ie6 lte9 lte8 lte7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>     <div class="ie ie7 lte9 lte8 lte7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>     <div class="ie ie8 lte9 lte8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]>     <div class="ie ie9 lte9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 9]>  <div> <![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!--> <div>             <!--<![endif]-->
  <div class="wrapper">
    I have a tooltip.
    <div class="tooltip">I am a tooltip!</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: #ececec;
  color: #555;
  cursor: help;
  font-family: "Gill Sans", Impact, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 100px 75px 10px 75px;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0); /* webkit flicker fix */
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; /* webkit text rendering fix */
}

.wrapper .tooltip {
  background: #1496bb;
  bottom: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  left: -25px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(10px);
     -moz-transform: translateY(10px);
      -ms-transform: translateY(10px);
       -o-transform: translateY(10px);
          transform: translateY(10px);
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease-out;
     -moz-transition: all .25s ease-out;
      -ms-transition: all .25s ease-out;
       -o-transition: all .25s ease-out;
          transition: all .25s ease-out;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
     -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
      -ms-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
       -o-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
          box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
}

/* This bridges the gap so you can mouse into the tooltip without it disappearing */
.wrapper .tooltip:before {
  bottom: -20px;
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}  

/* CSS Triangles - see Trevor's post */
.wrapper .tooltip:after {
  border-left: solid transparent 10px;
  border-right: solid transparent 10px;
  border-top: solid #1496bb 10px;
  bottom: -10px;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -13px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
}

.wrapper:hover .tooltip {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
     -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
      -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
       -o-transform: translateY(0px);
          transform: translateY(0px);
}

/* IE can just show/hide with no transition */
.lte8 .wrapper .tooltip {
  display: none;
}

.lte8 .wrapper:hover .tooltip {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: This is gross overkill for the task, but I don't think the downvote is appropriate.

Comment: _"If you are sure about pure css"_ Well is it working? Yes. But someone has too much reps it seems, and there is no explanation for down vote. I love people! 3<

Comment: @Ertürk Öztürk - Thanks for sharing this, very useful. I found it backwards by googling for "pure css tooltip" then googling for pages that listed the jsfiddle link :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you move `html` of `.content` to be adjacent sibling of `a` element; set `position` of `.content` to `absolute`, adjust `left` , `top` properties to match position of first `.col` element , you should be able to render `.content` within viewport similar to position of a child element of first `.col` element; that is , above `a` element; or at any position within viewport. Given that `.content` `display` is set to `none` , it should not matter if `.content` is placed next to `a` element within `html`

```css
.col:nth-of-type(1) {
  top: 0px;
  left:0px;
}

.content {
  display: none;
}
.navigation ul li a:hover + .content {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left:0px;
  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col">
</div>
<div class="col">
  <div class="navigation">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">punkt</a>
        <div class="content">lorem ipsum</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cool solution. Even more if the `.content` elements need to overlap to allow a nice fade fx (than in any case they *have* to be `absolute` positioned)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan There may be other possible `css` solutions; still trying alternatives

Comment: The only other solution you can get is using `click`s and radio elements; or again clicks and the `:target` pseudo.

Comment: Yes, trying with `:target`, though may require a user action other than `:hover`

Comment: There's no other way. You can move to a next question :)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan _"There's no other way."_ See new Answer using `::before` pseudo element

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan `:target` may require a `click` to adjust `css` of fragment identifier

Answer (score 1):

Another `css` approach would be to utilize `::before` pseudo element, again setting `position:absolute` , adjusting `top`, `left` values to render text or `url` at specific position within viewport

```css
a:hover::before {
  content: "lorem ipsum\A";
  position: absolute;
  display:block;
  top:8px;
  left:60px;
  color:green;
}
```

```html
<div class="col">
  <div class="content">content:</div>
</div>
<div class="col">
  <div class="navigation">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">punkt</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you insert the content using a CMS? It's easy to style / insert content using HTML tags inside a `:after` or `:before` pseudo elements?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan _"Can you insert the content using a CMS?"_ Not certain interpret this portion of comment correctly; have not tried CMS here. _"It's easy to style / insert content using HTML tags inside a :after or :before pseudo elements?"_ Should be able to use text or `url()` at `content` property where value could be a `data URI` or url to an external resource , for example an image , could be rendered https://jsfiddle.net/95yoff8e/

Comment: Really? Have you tried to insert HTML from a say `page.html` using the :after or :before pseudo?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Actually have tried a fair amount of attempting to render different types of data at `content` ; both using `data URI` and embedding data at an attribute of element

Comment: *A fair amount of time* does not mean it's (still) possible :)

Comment: Well, the text would need to be escaped, and `url()` or `attr()` does not parse `html`, though, yes, possible to render text to appear like an `html` document; `content`, generally, expects text. For example, if took a screenshot of an `html` document, that image could be rendered at `content`, otherwise, text would be rendered https://jsfiddle.net/95yoff8e/1/

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan An example of basic escaping and text formatting https://jsfiddle.net/95yoff8e/2/

Comment: Nice, I know, As you can see in my comment I was referring to URI like some page  `content.html`. Also, escaping HTML inside "content: " is clearly not something I would suggest to anyone - to insert HTML using the content property.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Not absolutely sure that `content` can, or cannot parse `html` ; though that is a good Question. Most of the attempts tried here used `html` or unicode escape sequences to render text that appeared similar to `html`. Do not believe stated that rendering an `.html` document was possible ? Would have to dig through some older projects to how far tried to bend `content` .

Comment: Yes, I just interveined cause MDN states `url(test.html)` as a valid url. Images are fine, but... I have not the time right now to dig into. Thanks for your time though

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan _"Also, escaping HTML inside "content: " is clearly not something I would suggest to anyone"_ Why not ? `html` escape sequences should return expected results where `white-space:pre` is set

Comment: Why use the term "silly" ? Is that necessary ? We were discussing how far `content` can be bent; how is this "silly" ?

Comment: I think you're getting me wrong Guest27... I'm saying that content should be used as a helper, not as a way to include large portions of HTML markup into your documents. Nice founds and talking anyways! :)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Both `data-*` attribute and `<data></data>`  element were, if not mistaken,  designed to contain portable, "machine-readable" content. Parsing or rendering that data in a particular format within an `html` document is the limiatation we were discussing attempting to define the limits of ? _"I'm saying that content should be used as a helper, not as a way to include large portions of HTML markup into your documents."_ Depends on application. _"Nice founds and talking anyways! :)"_  To you the same. Cheers

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan _"Yes, I just interveined cause MDN states url(test.html) as a valid url."_ Can you post link to MDN page ?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan _"cause MDN states url(test.html) as a valid url."_ Where does the documentation state `test.html`  as a valid url ?

Comment: Well, http://jsbin.com/zozetaj/1/edit?html,css,js,output see for your self. That's my effort in getting content from a valid URI. AJAX does the job perfectly, but  clearly `content: url(does not)`.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36072936/is-it-possible-to-display-an-html-document-or-html-fragment-at-css-content