# Is it possible to display an .html document , or .html fragment at CSS content?

Tags: html, css

At [documentation for `css` `content` at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/content) :

> ```
> /* <uri> value */ 
> content: url(http://www.example.com/test.html);
> ```

---

Question:

It is possible to display an image at the `css` `content` property of `html` element at `url()` value of `content`

```css
.content {
  content: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAScAAADBCAYAAACNMHZqAAAABHNCSVQICAgIfAhkiAAAApJJREFUeJzt1DEBwCAQwMCnynEOBrqT4U5BpqzZcwYg5nsdAPDHnIAkcwKSzAlIMicgyZyAJHMCkswJSDInIMmcgCRzApLMCUgyJyDJnIAkcwKSzAlIMicgyZyAJHMCkswJSDInIMmcgCRzApLMCUgyJyDJnIAkcwKSzAlIMicgyZyAJHMCkswJSDInIMmcgCRzApLMCUgyJyDJnIAkcwKSzAlIMicgyZyAJHMCkswJSDInIMmcgCRzApLMCUgyJyDJnIAkcwKSzAlIMicgyZyAJHMCkswJSDInIMmcgCRzApLMCUgyJyDJnIAkcwKSzAlIMicgyZyAJHMCkswJSDInIMmcgCRzApLMCUgyJyDJnIAkcwKSzAlIMicgyZyAJHMCkswJSDInIMmcgCRzApLMCUgyJyDJnIAkcwKSzAlIMicgyZyAJHMCkswJSDInIMmcgCRzApLMCUgyJyDJnIAkcwKSzAlIMicgyZyAJHMCkswJSDInIMmcgCRzApLMCUgyJyDJnIAkcwKSzAlIMicgyZyAJHMCkswJSDInIMmcgCRzApLMCUgyJyDJnIAkcwKSzAlIMicgyZyAJHMCkswJSDInIMmcgCRzApLMCUgyJyDJnIAkcwKSzAlIMicgyZyAJHMCkswJSDInIMmcgCRzApLMCUgyJyDJnIAkcwKSzAlIMicgyZyAJHMCkswJSDInIMmcgCRzApLMCUgyJyDJnIAkcwKSzAlIMicgyZyAJHMCkswJSDInIMmcgCRzApLMCUgyJyDJnIAkcwKSzAlIMicgyZyAJHMCkswJSDInIMmcgCRzApLMCUgyJyDJnIAkcwKSzAlIMicgyZyAJHMCkswJSDInIMmcgCRzApLMCUi6PDoDAbyCsn8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=);
}
```

```html
<div class="content"></div>
```

or using `content` property at a pseudo element, for example `::before`

```css
.content::before {
  content: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAScAAADBCAYAAACNMHZqAAAABHNCSVQICAgIfAhkiAAAApJJREFUeJzt1DEBwCAQwMCnynEOBrqT4U5BpqzZcwYg5nsdAPDHnIAkcwKSzAlIMicgyZyAJHMCkswJSDInIMmcgCRzApLMCUgyJyDJnIAkcwKSzAlIMicgyZyAJHMCkswJSDInIMmcgCRzApLMCUgyJyDJnIAkcwKSzAlIMicgyZyAJHMCkswJSDInIMmcgCRzApLMCUgyJyDJnIAkcwKSzAlIMicgyZyAJHMCkswJSDInIMmcgCRzApLMCUgyJyDJnIAkcwKSzAlIMicgyZyAJHMCkswJSDInIMmcgCRzApLMCUgyJyDJnIAkcwKSzAlIMicgyZyAJHMCkswJSDInIMmcgCRzApLMCUgyJyDJnIAkcwKSzAlIMicgyZyAJHMCkswJSDInIMmcgCRzApLMCUgyJyDJnIAkcwKSzAlIMicgyZyAJHMCkswJSDInIMmcgCRzApLMCUgyJyDJnIAkcwKSzAlIMicgyZyAJHMCkswJSDInIMmcgCRzApLMCUgyJyDJnIAkcwKSzAlIMicgyZyAJHMCkswJSDInIMmcgCRzApLMCUgyJyDJnIAkcwKSzAlIMicgyZyAJHMCkswJSDInIMmcgCRzApLMCUgyJyDJnIAkcwKSzAlIMicgyZyAJHMCkswJSDInIMmcgCRzApLMCUgyJyDJnIAkcwKSzAlIMicgyZyAJHMCkswJSDInIMmcgCRzApLMCUgyJyDJnIAkcwKSzAlIMicgyZyAJHMCkswJSDInIMmcgCRzApLMCUgyJyDJnIAkcwKSzAlIMicgyZyAJHMCkswJSDInIMmcgCRzApLMCUgyJyDJnIAkcwKSzAlIMicgyZyAJHMCkswJSDInIMmcgCRzApLMCUi6PDoDAbyCsn8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=);
}
```

```html
<div class="content"></div>
```

---

Is it possible to render an `.html` document , `.html` element at `css` `content` ?

```css
.content {
  content: url(data:text/html,abc);
}
```

```html
<div class="content"></div>
```

---

See also [CSS Generated Content Module Level 3](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-content-3/#inserting-replacing-content)

> The `content` property dictates what is rendered inside the element or
>   pseudo-element. It takes a comma separated list of URIs, followed by a
>   space separated list of tokens. If there are multiple URIs provided,
>   then each is tried in turn until a value which is both available and
>   supported is found. The last value is used as a fallback if the others
>   fail.
>
> [<uri>](https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/syndata.html#value-def-uri) For URIs other than URIs in the last comma separated
>   section of the value, if the URI is available and the format is
>   supported, then the element or pseudo-element becomes a replaced
>   element, otherwise, the next item in the comma separated list is used,
>   if any.
>
> EXAMPLE 4
>
> `h1 { content: url(header/mng), url(header/png), none; }`
>
> In the example above, if `header/mng` wasn’t in a supported format, then `header/png` would have been used instead. In the example above, if `header/png` wasn’t available either, then the `<h1>` element would be empty, as the last alternative is none.
>
> To make an element fallback on its contents, you have to explicitly
>   give [contents](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-content-3/#valdef-content-contents) as a fallback:
>
> EXAMPLE 5
>
> `content: url(1), url(2), url(3), contents;`
>
> ISSUE 3 What happens when no formats are supported, and the author
>   does not explicitly indicate a fallback?
>
> ISSUE 4 Why doesn’t an element fallback to contents unless an author
>   explicitly says so?

---

Update

The furthest have been able to reach, here, to embedding and displaying `html` document in `css` generated content; using approach demonstrated by @LGSon. Included `css` generated content within `html` at `svg` as well.

As noted by @RokoC.Buljan, the MIME type is not `"text/html"`.

```css
content {
  content: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBzdGFuZGFsb25lPSJ5ZXMiPz4KPHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSI0MDBweCIgaGVpZ2h0PSI0MDBweCIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDQwMCAzMDAiPgogICAgPGZvcmVpZ25PYmplY3Qgd2lkdGg9IjQwMHB4IiBoZWlnaHQ9IjMwMHB4IiAKICAgICByZXF1aXJlZEZlYXR1cmVzPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy9UUi9TVkcxMS9mZWF0dXJlI0V4dGVuc2liaWxpdHkiPgogICAgICA8aHRtbCB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMTk5OS94aHRtbCI+PGhlYWQ+PHN0eWxlIHR5cGU9InRleHQvY3NzIj5jb250ZW50e2NvbnRlbnQ6dXJsKCJkYXRhOmltYWdlL3BuZztiYXNlNjQsaVZCT1J3MEtHZ29BQUFBTlNVaEVVZ0FBQVNjQUFBRERDQVlBQUFEQStOZGhBQUFBQkhOQ1NWUUlDQWdJZkFoa2lBQUFBcGxKUkVGVWVKenQxQ0VCQUNBQXdEQ2dmdzF5UWdFOEYxdUNxOCt6eHhrQU1ldDNBTUNMT1FGSjVnUWttUk9RWkU1QWtqa0JTZVlFSkprVGtHUk9RSkk1QVVubUJDU1pFNUJrVGtDU09RRko1Z1FrbVJPUVpFNUFramtCU2VZRUpKa1RrR1JPUUpJNUFVbm1CQ1NaRTVCa1RrQ1NPUUZKNWdRa21ST1FaRTVBa2prQlNlWUVKSmtUa0dST1FKSTVBVW5tQkNTWkU1QmtUa0NTT1FGSjVnUWttUk9RWkU1QWtqa0JTZVlFSkprVGtHUk9RSkk1QVVubUJDU1pFNUJrVGtDU09RRko1Z1FrbVJPUVpFNUFramtCU2VZRUpKa1RrR1JPUUpJNUFVbm1CQ1NaRTVCa1RrQ1NPUUZKNWdRa21ST1FaRTVBa2prQlNlWUVKSmtUa0dST1FKSTVBVW5tQkNTWkU1QmtUa0NTT1FGSjVnUWttUk9RWkU1QWtqa0JTZVlFSkprVGtHUk9RSkk1QVVubUJDU1pFNUJrVGtDU09RRko1Z1FrbVJPUVpFNUFramtCU2VZRUpKa1RrR1JPUUpJNUFVbm1CQ1NaRTVCa1RrQ1NPUUZKNWdRa21ST1FaRTVBa2prQlNlWUVKSmtUa0dST1FKSTVBVW5tQkNTWkU1QmtUa0NTT1FGSjVnUWttUk9RWkU1QWtqa0JTZVlFSkprVGtHUk9RSkk1QVVubUJDU1pFNUJrVGtDU09RRko1Z1FrbVJPUVpFNUFramtCU2VZRUpKa1RrR1JPUUpJNUFVbm1CQ1NaRTVCa1RrQ1NPUUZKNWdRa21ST1FaRTVBa2prQlNlWUVKSmtUa0dST1FKSTVBVW5tQkNTWkU1QmtUa0NTT1FGSjVnUWttUk9RWkU1QWtqa0JTZVlFSkprVGtHUk9RSkk1QVVubUJDU1pFNUJrVGtDU09RRko1Z1FrbVJPUVpFNUFramtCU2VZRUpKa1RrR1JPUUpJNUFVbm1CQ1NaRTVCa1RrQ1NPUUZKNWdRa21ST1FaRTVBa2prQlNlWUVKSmtUa0dST1FKSTVBVW5tQkNTWkU1QmtUa0NTT1FGSjVnUWttUk9RWkU1QWtqa0JTZVlFSkprVGtHUk9RSkk1QVVubUJDU1pFNUJrVGtDU09RRkpGMlBYQkNtc0t5TUpBQUFBQUVsRlRrU3VRbUNDIil9PC9zdHlsZT48L2hlYWQ+PGJvZHkgc3R5bGU9ImJvcmRlcjp0aGljayBzb2xpZCB5ZWxsb3c7YmFja2dyb3VuZDp1cmwoZGF0YTppbWFnZS9wbmc7YmFzZTY0LGlWQk9SdzBLR2dvQUFBQU5TVWhFVWdBQUFTY0FBQURCQ0FZQUFBQ05NSFpxQUFBQUJITkNTVlFJQ0FnSWZBaGtpQUFBQXBKSlJFRlVlSnp0MURFQndDQVF3TUNueW5FT0JycVQ0VTVCcHF6WmN3WWc1bnNkQVBESG5JQWtjd0tTekFsSU1pY2d5WnlBSkhNQ2tzd0pTREluSU1tY2dDUnpBcExNQ1VneUp5REpuSUFrY3dLU3pBbElNaWNneVp5QUpITUNrc3dKU0RJbklNbWNnQ1J6QXBMTUNVZ3lKeURKbklBa2N3S1N6QWxJTWljZ3laeUFKSE1Da3N3SlNESW5JTW1jZ0NSekFwTE1DVWd5SnlESm5JQWtjd0tTekFsSU1pY2d5WnlBSkhNQ2tzd0pTREluSU1tY2dDUnpBcExNQ1VneUp5REpuSUFrY3dLU3pBbElNaWNneVp5QUpITUNrc3dKU0RJbklNbWNnQ1J6QXBMTUNVZ3lKeURKbklBa2N3S1N6QWxJTWljZ3laeUFKSE1Da3N3SlNESW5JTW1jZ0NSekFwTE1DVWd5SnlESm5JQWtjd0tTekFsSU1pY2d5WnlBSkhNQ2tzd0pTREluSU1tY2dDUnpBcExNQ1VneUp5REpuSUFrY3dLU3pBbElNaWNneVp5QUpITUNrc3dKU0RJbklNbWNnQ1J6QXBMTUNVZ3lKeURKbklBa2N3S1N6QWxJTWljZ3laeUFKSE1Da3N3SlNESW5JTW1jZ0NSekFwTE1DVWd5SnlESm5JQWtjd0tTekFsSU1pY2d5WnlBSkhNQ2tzd0pTREluSU1tY2dDUnpBcExNQ1VneUp5REpuSUFrY3dLU3pBbElNaWNneVp5QUpITUNrc3dKU0RJbklNbWNnQ1J6QXBMTUNVZ3lKeURKbklBa2N3S1N6QWxJTWljZ3laeUFKSE1Da3N3SlNESW5JTW1jZ0NSekFwTE1DVWd5SnlESm5JQWtjd0tTekFsSU1pY2d5WnlBSkhNQ2tzd0pTREluSU1tY2dDUnpBcExNQ1VneUp5REpuSUFrY3dLU3pBbElNaWNneVp5QUpITUNrc3dKU0RJbklNbWNnQ1J6QXBMTUNVZ3lKeURKbklBa2N3S1N6QWxJTWljZ3laeUFKSE1Da3N3SlNESW5JTW1jZ0NSekFwTE1DVWd5SnlESm5JQWtjd0tTekFsSU1pY2d5WnlBSkhNQ2tzd0pTREluSU1tY2dDUnpBcExNQ1VpNlBEb0RBYnlDc244QUFBQUFTVVZPUks1Q1lJST0pIj48aDE+VGV4dCBnb2VzIGhlcmU8L2gxPjxpbWcgc3JjPSJncmVlbi5wbmciPjwvaW1nPjxkaWFsb2cgc3R5bGU9InRvcDoxNTBweDsiIG9wZW49InRydWUiPmNvbnRlbnQ8L2RpYWxvZz48Y29udGVudD48L2NvbnRlbnQ+PC9ib2R5PjwvaHRtbD4KICAgIDwvZm9yZWlnbk9iamVjdD4KPC9zdmc+Cg==)
}
```

```html
<content></content>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="400px" height="400px" viewBox="0 0 400 300">
    <foreignObject width="400px" height="300px" 
     requiredFeatures="http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#Extensibility">
      <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><style type="text/css">content{content:url("data:image/png;base64,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")}</style></head><body style="border:thick solid yellow;background:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAScAAADBCAYAAACNMHZqAAAABHNCSVQICAgIfAhkiAAAApJJREFUeJzt1DEBwCAQwMCnynEOBrqT4U5BpqzZcwYg5nsdAPDHnIAkcwKSzAlIMicgyZyAJHMCkswJSDInIMmcgCRzApLMCUgyJyDJnIAkcwKSzAlIMicgyZyAJHMCkswJSDInIMmcgCRzApLMCUgyJyDJnIAkcwKSzAlIMicgyZyAJHMCkswJSDInIMmcgCRzApLMCUgyJyDJnIAkcwKSzAlIMicgyZyAJHMCkswJSDInIMmcgCRzApLMCUgyJyDJnIAkcwKSzAlIMicgyZyAJHMCkswJSDInIMmcgCRzApLMCUgyJyDJnIAkcwKSzAlIMicgyZyAJHMCkswJSDInIMmcgCRzApLMCUgyJyDJnIAkcwKSzAlIMicgyZyAJHMCkswJSDInIMmcgCRzApLMCUgyJyDJnIAkcwKSzAlIMicgyZyAJHMCkswJSDInIMmcgCRzApLMCUgyJyDJnIAkcwKSzAlIMicgyZyAJHMCkswJSDInIMmcgCRzApLMCUgyJyDJnIAkcwKSzAlIMicgyZyAJHMCkswJSDInIMmcgCRzApLMCUgyJyDJnIAkcwKSzAlIMicgyZyAJHMCkswJSDInIMmcgCRzApLMCUgyJyDJnIAkcwKSzAlIMicgyZyAJHMCkswJSDInIMmcgCRzApLMCUgyJyDJnIAkcwKSzAlIMicgyZyAJHMCkswJSDInIMmcgCRzApLMCUgyJyDJnIAkcwKSzAlIMicgyZyAJHMCkswJSDInIMmcgCRzApLMCUgyJyDJnIAkcwKSzAlIMicgyZyAJHMCkswJSDInIMmcgCRzApLMCUgyJyDJnIAkcwKSzAlIMicgyZyAJHMCkswJSDInIMmcgCRzApLMCUi6PDoDAbyCsn8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=)"><h1>Text goes here</h1><img src="green.png"></img><dialog style="top:150px;" open="true">content</dialog><content></content></body></html>
    </foreignObject>
</svg>
```

---

[content](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-content/#content) , [3.4. Resource Locators: the `<url>` type](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-3/#urls)

Comment: Nope, the closest you can get is SVG ... which is quite a lot actually

Comment: @LGSon `svg` is a `document` which can render text , yes ?

Comment: @LGSon Would you consider posting a solution ?

Comment: This will probably change, but currently the `content` property only applies to `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements.

Comment: @Oriol Believe `content` can be applied at an element without using a pseudo element. See first stacksnippet at Question

Comment: @guest271314 Precisely, the specification link in your question says "Applies to: `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements". [CSS Generated Content Module Level 3](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-content-3/#inserting-replacing-content) might change that, but currently is only a draft not ready for implementation.

Comment: @Oriol At chromium 50 the image is rendered at first stacksnippet, as a green rectangle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MDN (*erroneously?*) states that it's possible](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/content)...

> **<uri> value**
>   content: url(http://www.example.com/test.html);

o_O Probably a misinterpretation of the [Recommendation Specifications](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#propdef-content) and the basic difference between **URL** (restrictive to certain MIME types) and **URI** in general.

While as you can see in **[this example](http://jsbin.com/zozetaj/1/edit?html,css,js,output)** AJAX does the job perfectly,
  while `content: url(someValidHTMLUri.html)` does not work for `text/[html, ...]`, as opposed to MIME types Content-transfer-encoding like `application/`, `image/`, ...

http://jsbin.com/zozetaj/1/edit?html,css,js,output

> https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/content
>   The value is a URI that designates an external resource (such as an image). If the user agent cannot display the resource it must either leave it out as if it were not specified or display some indication that the resource cannot be displayed.

Comment: _"MDN states that it's possible"_ Can you include link to MDN documentation where described being possible to use `.html` at `content` ?

Comment: Ah, see it now at `<uri>`

Comment: @guest271314 if you think there's no error in the documentation than feel free to use `content: url(http://www.example.com/test.html);` -

Comment: An listed contributor to documentation appears to be an SO user http://stackoverflow.com/users/432681/sebastian-zartner ; perhaps they will chime in as to `.html` extension description . How to "ping" an SO user ?

Comment: @guest271314 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Interactive_content - I can edit the MDN docs, but I don't have the time right now. I'll flag as "In need of review"

Comment: @guest271314 good move. I've also set the request for technical review. I'll look more into it this days.

Comment: @RokoCBuljan Marked `Status: RESOLVED FIXED` though `/* <uri> value */
content: url(http://www.example.com/test.html);` appears to remain within text at documentation

Answer (score 6):

*Updated to clarify, that this SVG solution is posted based on [a request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36072936/is-it-possible-to-display-an-html-document-or-html-fragment-at-css-content/36073310?#comment59792139_36072936) made by the OP.*

Here are a few samples, as an alternative, since normal HTML document doesn't get rendered (yet), where a SVG is used, using both `css` `content` and pseudo element `css` `content` property.

Note, it renders as an `image/svg+xml`, though the 2:nd sample show it can contain HTML elements.

```css
div {
  height: 120px;
  background: gray;
}
div:before {
  content: url(data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%27http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%27%20width%3D%27200%27%20height%3D%27100%27%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%2720%27%20y%3D%2745%27%20font-size%3D%2713px%27%3EHello%20World%20from%20SVG%3C%2Ftext%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E);
}
div:after {
  content: url(data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20version%3D%221.1%22%20height%3D%2280%22%20width%3D%22160%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3Ccircle%20cx%3D%2240%22%20cy%3D%2240%22%20r%3D%2238%22%20stroke%3D%22black%22%20stroke-width%3D%221%22%20fill%3D%22red%22%20%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3Ccircle%20cx%3D%22120%22%20cy%3D%2240%22%20r%3D%2238%22%20stroke%3D%22black%22%20stroke-width%3D%221%22%20fill%3D%22blue%22%20%2F%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fsvg%3E);
}

span {
  height: 120px;
  background: gray;
  content: url(data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%27http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%27%20width%3D%27200%27%20height%3D%27100%27%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%2720%27%20y%3D%2745%27%20font-size%3D%2713px%27%3EHello%20World%20from%20SVG%3C%2Ftext%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<span></span>
```

Decoded SVG

```
<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='200' height='100'>
  <text x='20' y='45' font-size='13px'>Hello World from SVG</text>
</svg>
```

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" height="80" width="160">
  <circle cx="40" cy="40" r="38" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="red" />
  <circle cx="120" cy="40" r="38" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="blue" />
</svg>
```

---

**Updated:** Added the commented [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/NsoYwZ4Y1IWSaZRhZM9Z?p=preview) sample that also contain `html`/`xml` elements.

```css
.content:before {
  content: url(data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20width%3D%22100%25%22%20height%3D%22300%22%3E%0A%20%20%3Crect%20x%3D%2210%22%20y%3D%2210%22%20width%3D%22100%22%20height%3D%22150%22%20fill%3D%22blue%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%3CforeignObject%20x%3D%2210%22%20y%3D%2210%22%20width%3D%22100%22%20height%3D%22150%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2Fxhtml%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Here%20is%20a%20%3Cstrong%3Eparagraph%3C%2Fstrong%3E%20that%20requires%20%3Cem%3Eword%20wrap%3C%2Fem%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2FforeignObject%3E%0A%20%0A%20%20%3Ccircle%20cx%3D%22200%22%20cy%3D%22200%22%20r%3D%22100%22%20fill%3D%22red%22%20%2F%3E%0A%20%20%3CforeignObject%20x%3D%22120%22%20y%3D%22120%22%20width%3D%22180%22%20height%3D%22180%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2Fxhtml%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cul%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cli%3E%3Cstrong%3EFirst%3C%2Fstrong%3E%20item%3C%2Fli%3E%0A%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cli%3E%3Cem%3ESecond%3C%2Fem%3E%20item%3C%2Fli%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cli%3EThrid%20item%3C%2Fli%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ful%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2FforeignObject%3E%0A%3C%2Fsvg%3E%0A);
    }

.content2 {
  content: url(data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20width%3D%22100%25%22%20height%3D%22300%22%3E%0A%20%20%3Crect%20x%3D%2210%22%20y%3D%2210%22%20width%3D%22100%22%20height%3D%22150%22%20fill%3D%22blue%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%3CforeignObject%20x%3D%2210%22%20y%3D%2210%22%20width%3D%22100%22%20height%3D%22150%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2Fxhtml%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Here%20is%20a%20%3Cstrong%3Eparagraph%3C%2Fstrong%3E%20that%20requires%20%3Cem%3Eword%20wrap%3C%2Fem%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2FforeignObject%3E%0A%20%0A%20%20%3Ccircle%20cx%3D%22200%22%20cy%3D%22200%22%20r%3D%22100%22%20fill%3D%22red%22%20%2F%3E%0A%20%20%3CforeignObject%20x%3D%22120%22%20y%3D%22120%22%20width%3D%22180%22%20height%3D%22180%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2Fxhtml%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cul%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cli%3E%3Cstrong%3EFirst%3C%2Fstrong%3E%20item%3C%2Fli%3E%0A%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cli%3E%3Cem%3ESecond%3C%2Fem%3E%20item%3C%2Fli%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cli%3EThrid%20item%3C%2Fli%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ful%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2FforeignObject%3E%0A%3C%2Fsvg%3E%0A);
    }
```

```html
<content class="content"></content>
<content class="content2"></content>
```

Decoded SVG

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="300">
  <rect x="10" y="10" width="100" height="150" fill="blue"/>
  <foreignObject x="10" y="10" width="100" height="150">
      <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
          Here is a <strong>paragraph</strong> that requires <em>word wrap</em></div>
  </foreignObject>

  <circle cx="200" cy="200" r="100" fill="red" />
  <foreignObject x="120" y="120" width="180" height="180">
      <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <ul>
          <li><strong>First</strong> item</li>

          <li><em>Second</em> item</li>
          <li>Thrid item</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
  </foreignObject>
</svg>
```

Comment: As I stated the MIME type is `image/` therefore **not a text/html**

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan No worries, asked LGSon to consider providing a solution at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36072936/is-it-possible-to-display-an-html-document-or-html-fragment-at-css-content/36073310#comment59792139_36072936 . If `html` cannot be achieved , closest workaround would be useful . Should Question be updated to include any `document` ?

Comment: @LGSon Unsuccessful attempt to use `foreignObject` to embed `html` http://plnkr.co/edit/M77k38diK9cbnMlRB7CL?p=preview

Comment: @guest271314 You forgot the `xmlns` attribute .. updated plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/NsoYwZ4Y1IWSaZRhZM9Z?p=preview

Comment: @guest271314 Decide to also add that sample to my answer, hope that was okay, as I think it is a good sample and good to have it as a stack snippet.

Comment: @guest271314 Have you been able to verify the updated code sample?

Comment: @LGSon Yes. `html` elements appear to be displayed at both stacksnippets  and plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/NsoYwZ4Y1IWSaZRhZM9Z?p=preview . Which element did not have `xmlns` attribute ?

Comment: @guest271314 The SVG element

Comment: Several approaches that have been unsuccessful: including `<!DOCTYPE html>` declaration , does not render `html`; including `onload="alert()"`, does not render `html`; `animation` of element, appears to ignore `animation` , `@keyframes`; including `<script></script>` within `html` document, `alert` is not called.

Comment: @guest271314 Of course you will not be able to do **all** the things a HTML document does for the same reason HTML can't do all the stuff a SVG can, so bottom line, this is a SVG document which render as image, still, it offers way more than just being a simple png/jpg image. Look for the things it can do instead for the one's it can't ... and SVG has its own animation: http://plnkr.co/edit/I7C3LSl8sg4KGkHn23xB?p=preview

Comment: @LGSon Yes, you are correct. Have yet to determine if example at MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/content `content: url(http://www.example.com/test.html);` is accurate or not.

Comment: @guest271314 Me too, so please post a comment here when you know, as this is really interesting.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but your first example doesn't appear at all relevant to the question, since the question is about HTML, not SVG. At the very least the second example describes an SVG that contains HTML in a foreignObject, which answers the question somewhat. If you're trying to convey that it is not possible to embed an HTML document via the content property, you should state this directly, rather than post a non-sequitur.

Comment: @BoltClock Thanks for your response. [OP asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36072936/is-it-possible-to-display-an-html-document-or-html-fragment-at-css-content/36073310?noredirect=1#comment59792139_36072936) if I could post an SVG alternative, since that is a way (kind of) to have HTML element displayed using CSS `content`. I will update and make a note about that.

Comment: Thanks, sorry I had missed that.