# What is an example usage of <url-modifier> at CSS url() function?

Tags: css

[3.4. Resource Locators: the `<url>` type](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-values/#url-value) describes a `<url-modifier>` at

> A ***URL*** is a pointer to a resource and is a functional notation
>   denoted by `<url>`. The syntax of a `<url>` is:
>
> `<url> = url( <string> <url-modifier>* )`
>
> In addition to the syntax defined above, a  can sometimes be
>   written in other ways:
>
> - For legacy reasons, a `<url>` can be written without quotation marks around the URL itself. This syntax is specially-parsed, and
>     produces a `<url-token>` rather than a function syntactically.
>     [[CSS3SYN](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-values/#biblio-css3syn)]
> - Some CSS contexts, such as [`@import`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-cascade-4/#at-ruledef-import), allow a `<url>` to be represented by a [`<string>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-values/#string-value) instead. This behaves identically to
>     writing a `url()` function containing that string. Because these
>     alternate ways of writing a `<url>` are not functional notations, they
>     cannot accept any `<url-modifier>`s.
>
> Note: The special parsing rules for the legacy quotation mark-less
>   `<url>` syntax means that parentheses, whitespace characters, single
>   quotes (') and double quotes (") appearing in a URL must be escaped
>   with a backslash, e.g. `url(open\(parens)`, `url(close\)parens)`.
>   Depending on the type of URL, it might also be possible to write these
>   characters as URL-escapes (e.g. `url(open%28parens)` or
>   `url(close%29parens)`) as described in[[URL](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-values/#biblio-url)]. (If written as a
>   normal function containing a string, ordinary string escaping rules
>   apply; only newlines and the character used to quote the string need
>   to be escaped.)

at

> [**3.4.2. URL Modifiers**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-values/#typedef-url-modifier)
>
> The `url()` function supports specifying additional `<url-modifier>`s,
>   which change the meaning or the interpretation of the URL somehow. A
>   `<url-modifier>` is either an [`<ident>`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/mediaqueries-4/#typedef-ident) or a [function](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-syntax-3/#function).
>
> This specification does not define any `<url-modifier>`s, but other
>   specs may do so.

See also [CSS Values and Units Module Level 3
Editor’s Draft, 21 March 2016](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values/#biblio-whatwg-url)

---

- What are example usages of `<ident>` and `function` at `url()` ?
- What are differences between `<string>` , `<ident>`, `function` at `url()` ?

Comment: This cannot be answered beyond what is already given in the quotations because there are no known <url-modifier> definitions in any specification. If you're looking for made-up examples, then this question is off-topic.

Comment: @BoltClock The specification defines that using a `<url-modifier>` is possible at `url()`. Question is asking how this available feature can be, or is implemented ? If the feature has been used in the wild, how so ? The second portion of Question is if there are differences between `<string>`, `<ident>` at `url()` function ? Not certain how this would be considered "off-topic" ? How can it be determined that no browser, or individual user has implemented the feature without asking ?

Comment: Putting aside the assumption that just because it's been defined in the spec means implementations must exist in the wild, the question is too broad. Even if you're asking for existing impls, you're still asking for a list that is likely to change as new definitions and new impls appear (and that isn't counting nonstandard impls, since technically every impl right now will be nonstandard). The second question can be answered partially and rather easily at that - the spec itself says a modifier can only either be an ident or a function, therefore <string> must represent the URL itself.

Comment: @BoltClock This Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36072936/is-it-possible-to-display-an-html-document-or-html-fragment-at-css-content is related to the degree that if a `<url-modifier>` could be implemented, could we use that feature to display an `.html` document at `url()` function at `content` ? Trying to find a procedure to interpret, pre-process an `.html` document in such a manner that it could be rendered without converting the document to an image or embedding an `svg`.

Comment: @BoltClock Also reviewed `Navigator.registerContentHandler()` , `Navigator.registerProtocolHandler()` to see if it is possible to use those features to assist in rendering an `.html` document or fragment at `css` `content`. Have tried using `.xhtml` with `xslt` instructions within document as well. The description of `<url-modifier>` appeared, here, as to be designed for, or left open for such an implementation; that is _"which change the meaning or the interpretation of the URL somehow"_ to allow rendering of document or fragment where would not be rendered otherwise

Comment: Regarding the <uri-modifier>, I'm not sure, since the spec doesn't provide any information to go on right now. Regarding your linked question, I'm sorry but I cannot answer it. You should update your question with your findings rather than report to me.

Comment: @BoltClock _"Regarding the <uri-modifier>, I'm not sure, since the spec doesn't provide any information to go on right now."_ Yes, this is why asked Question. _"You should update your question with your findings rather than report to me."_ What do you mean by "report" ? You are the only user here exchanging  communications. What would need to be updated ? That rendering of `.html` document is only this users' requirement; other users may find other uses for the feature

Comment: `url("/foo" bar)` and `url("/foo" bar(3))`, I presume. Since there are no implementations yet the question is moot imho.

Comment: @BoltClock fwiw sent request for clarification as to usage and  current browser implementations to w3c

Comment: @zeroflagL Do you mean the `<url modifier>` is intended to be a fragment identifier? Why presume? The authors of the specification or a user that has previously looked into the area or further or defined their own implementation could answer the questions?

Comment: The spec defines it as mere identifier or function. _"I presume"_ because the syntax looks strange. I would expect a comma between the arguments, but on the other hand: it's CSS.

Comment: http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2016Apr/0181.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A `<url-modifier>` is either an `<ident>` or a `function`.

`<ident>` is an identifier.

> A portion of the CSS source that has the same syntax as an `<ident-token>`.

[`<ident-token>` Syntax](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-syntax-3/#ident-token-diagram) ;

I could not find any examples of `<ident>` used within the `url` function but 
as mentioned in [this email](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2016Apr/0181.html) there are some possible future uses.

- Fetch options to control CORS/cookies/etc
- working with Subresource Integrity

Looking at the `<ident>` syntax you cannot use a key/value pair so i assume 
most of this would be implemented using a `function` which does not yet exist., resource hinting could be implemented using `<ident>`.

`.foo {
    background-image: url("//aa.com/img.svg" prefetch);
}`

I did however find a "A Collection of Interesting Ideas" with a `function` `<url-modifier>` defined.

[SVG Parameters](https://tabatkins.github.io/specs/svg-params/) (not official spec)

The [`params()`](https://tabatkins.github.io/specs/svg-params/#funcdef-param) `function` is a `<url-modifier>`

`.foo {
    background-image: url("//aa.com/img.svg" param(--color var(--primary-color)));
}`