# Is it feasible in term of rendering performance to create a whole webpage under one single HTML canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

Judging on rendering performance only, what would happen if the whole web page is done from scratch solely within `<canvas>` including everything such as text, images, event handling etc. ? How much of a difference would it make comparing to webpages that are made using tradition DOM creation method.

Comment: It depends on what's on the page, how dynamic it needs to be, if it needs to interpret css files etc. Don't underestimate how much browsers rely on OS-native features that are highly optimised, and that your code would have to cater for all target platforms

Comment: Have you tried each approach and logged the differences in time? Why use `<canvas>` to render? You could use an `<img>` element with `src` set to image of an `html` document

Comment: @guest271314 Wouldn't that make the web page lose its interactivity? Actually, I'm not planning to implement anything like this yet, I know it sounds like a terrible idea, but I'm just wondering about the possibility of ditching the whole DOM system and fully have the control of web page visualization pixel-by-pixel under canvas tag.

Comment: _"but I'm just wondering about the possibility of ditching the whole DOM system and fully have the control of web page visualization pixel-by-pixel under canvas tag"_ Original Question appears to be _"Is it feasible in term of rendering performance to create a whole webpage under one single HTML canvas?"_ . _"Wouldn't that make the web page lose its interactivity?"_ Yes, using `<img>` element, you could also use `<svg>` to include `html` document text within `<svg>` element, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/36072936/. Not certain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: What do you call a "*webpage*" ?  some Web Apps are made entirely based on the canvas API, but these are still in a DOM Webpage. You can create a Wolfenstein mockup in canvas element, so a simple webpage... But now take a step back, that would mean you'll have to translate yourself all of CSS renderings existing, to canvas commands. If you do that, don't hesitate one second to PR [this repro](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/), it's been years they're working on it, and they're good, and they still don't have it all.

Comment: I'm working on a client-side graphing project using mostly javascript and canvas, and I was wondering if there would be any potential limitations or performance issues if I draw everything under 'canvas' as a single page web app which would include all texts, buttons, transitions/UI animations, etc. since I'm not a fan of CSS and this is my first time experimenting with  'canvas' itself. But considering the amount of code needed to be written to achieve that, I wouldn't be doing it now, but knowing that it's possible and 3D games are written on it actually gave me quite a relief.

Comment: I create biz-apps and some of the data visualization pages are completely in <canvas>. Data-drilldown is particularly effective as a canvas-only page. IMO, if your page is only doing simple visualization as opposed to interactively creating content, then you might consider canvas-only. But at the point the user needs to do interact extensively with the page you really should add back the built-in html elements ("the right tools for the job").