# Jquery Parse JSON coming from an html element

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, parsing

I am trying to parse some JSON coming from the server into an object I can use in Javascript. The JSON is saved by the server inside a span. When I click on the action button, it should get the JSON and parse it into an object. Unfortunately, I get an exception. Please see the code:

```js
$(function(){
  $("#btn").click(function(elem){
    var elem = $("#content");
    var html = elem.html();
    console.log(html);
    var x = JSON.parse(html);
    console.log(x);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <button id="btn">Action</button>
    <br/><br/>
     <span id="content">{"test" : "<a href=\"http://cnn.com\">CNN</a> Hello"}</span>
</body>
```

I also tried it with the content in the span not escaping the ":

```
<span id="content">{"test" : "<a href="http://cnn.com">CNN</a> Hello"}</span>
```

Any idea how to solve?

Note for background: this is used inside an angular app which needs to receive the json to init the model.

Comment: Can you include `javascript` at Question where `JSON` returned from server is set as `html` of  `#content` element?

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what you need?

Comment: checklist: Is the `<a>` meant to display visually inside `#content`, or is `#content` hidden. This means of transferring JSON data is bound to fail, since the original HTML markup gets parsed into a DOM and discarded. The `.html()` call is not giving you the original markup. It generates it on the fly.

Comment: @checklist _"Sorry but I don't understand what you need?"_ How did you set the `html` of `#content` element? Would suggest using `.dataset` of element or `.data()` to store the `JSON`. You are probably losing exact `JSON` representation by using `.innerHTML` of element to convert back and forth.

Comment: @checklist _"I am trying to parse some JSON coming from the server"_ How do you retrieve `JSON` from server? Can you include that portion of `javascript` at Question?

Comment: The Json is embedded as part of the HTML returned when page loads and is placed in the span. It is exactly like in the sample code above.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass `html` to `JSON.stringify()`

```js
$(function(){
  $("#btn").click(function(elem){
    var elem = $("#content");
    var html = elem.html();
    console.log(html);
    var x = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(html));
    console.log(x);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <button id="btn">Action</button>
    <br/><br/>
     <span id="content">{"test" : "<a href=\"http://cnn.com\">CNN</a> Hello"}</span>
</body>
```

Comment: Why would they pass a string to `JSON.stringify`?

Comment: @squint Not sure gather your Question?

Comment: `html` is a string. You're passing it to `.stringify()`, which gives you a string back with some escaping. Then you pass that to `.parse()`, which gives you back the original `html`. You've made no progress; you're just back where you started.

Comment: @squint, it's escaping the quotes around `href=\"`

Comment: @squint _"You're passing it to .stringify(), which gives you a string back with some escaping."_ To escape the string.

Comment: @Maximus: Sure, then `parse` is unescaping them, so it's back to the original string. What progress has been made? It's still JSON, and if you try to parse `x`, it'll give the same error.

Comment: @guest271314, in your example you already escaped `href=\"`, so it's not obvious what's it doing. Change to unescaped and it'll be clear

Comment: @squint, parse does not give an error because the string returned from `stringify` is `"{\"test\" : \"<a href=\"http://cnn.com\">CNN</a> Hello\"}"`

Comment: @Maximus: Which parse? The one in this answer? It doesn't there because it's just parsing it from a doubly encoded string to a single encoded string. It's still not an object. In your answer, you end up with an object where you can access the `.test`. That's not the case here.

Comment: @squint, indeed, you're right, I can't access `.test` as `parse` returned a string. I never thought `parse` can return a string :). I guess I need to read more about how `stringify` and `parse` works

Comment: @Maximus: Yeah, the double encoding gets confusing. When a JSON string gets stringified, what gets returned is a JSON string of a JSON string, so a parse gets you back to the original JSON string.

Comment: @squint Yes. You are correct. Curious if the string at Question is actual `JSON` returned from server. The string inside of `<span>` is not `JSON`

Comment: @Maximus: If I remember correctly, the JSON standard requires that JSON data be an Object or Array structure at its outermost level. However, some parsers allow a number, boolean, string or null to stand alone as JSON. So if that's correct, technically `JSON.stringify(123)` and `JSON.parse("123")` should fail, but the parsers allow it. So that may be why MDN is worded the way it is. Or maybe it's just because MDN sometimes has mistakes. It is a wiki after all.

Comment: @guest271314: I haven't looked closely to see why it's failing, but transmitting JSON this way would be very fragile. The DOM isn't a string, so it gets parsed and made into nodes. Who knows what it'll look like when dynamically put back together as HTML.

Comment: @squint Concur, MDN does contain mistakes, or omissions; and even when aletered to the possible error, the error remains; see [Is it possible to display an .html document , or .html fragment at CSS content?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36072936/is-it-possible-to-display-an-html-document-or-html-fragment-at-css-content). Again, the string inside of `<span>` is not `JSON`; closer to an object literal

Comment: @guest271314: The text in the span is valid JSON. Go to http://jsonlint.com and paste it in to see that it's valid. It would be a valid object literal too if it were directly in a JavaScript program, but it's not. To make it JSON in a JS program, it would need outer quotes to delimit the start and end of the JSON string.

Comment: @squint _"To make it JSON in a JS program, it would need outer quotes to delimit the start and end of the JSON string."_ That is what meant.

Comment: @guest271314: Yes, but that's not part of making it JSON. That's just to indicate a string in a JS program. The way it is in the question, it's valid JSON inside the span, but I think it loses its escaped quotes or something when the DOM is parsed.

Comment: ...either way, it's a screwy way to transfer JSON data.

Comment: @squint _"it's a screwy way to transfer JSON data."_ If that is the actual data returned from server. That is, how did the string get to be set as `html` of `<span>` element? Appears to be object literal within `<span>`, not `JSON` which would come from server. Were the quotes removed from beginning and end of string? The process by which the `JSON` was set as `html` of `<span>` should also probably be demonstrated at OP.

Comment: @squint Perhaps OP omitted including the beginning and ending quotes at `html` of `<span>` element at Question? `var obj = {"test" : "<a href=\"http://cnn.com\">CNN</a> Hello"}; var str = JSON.stringify(obj); str; var obj1 = JSON.parse(str)`. `console.log(str)` does not include beginning and ending `"`. If `str` itself is entered at `console` the result is `"{"test":"<a href=\"http://cnn.com\">CNN</a> Hello"}"`

Comment: Object literal syntax and JSON syntax are (or can be) identical. They're just syntax. How/where they're used is what makes them JSON or object literal. There would be no start/end quotes to begin with, because that's not part of JSON. JSON is not JavaScript. They just (sometimes) look the same.

Comment: @squint What am trying to convey is that if `console.log(str)` is run the beginning and ending `"` are not printed, which could be how OP came to post `{"test" : "<a href=\"http://cnn.com\">CNN</a> Hello"}` at Question. Though if `str` alone is entered the result is `"{"test":"<a href=\"http://cnn.com\">CNN</a> Hello"}"`. To put it differently, how did `{"test" : "<a href=\"http://cnn.com\">CNN</a> Hello"}` wind up as `html` of `#content`?

Comment: @guest271314: Oh, I think they're just using the HTML document as a way to transfer the JSON data to the browser. *"...The JSON is saved by the server inside a span..."* So I think the OP is showing exactly how it gets sent from the server. A `data-` attribute would be better.

Comment: @squint Not sure how that could be the case. How can an object literal be set as `html` of an element? Using `JSON.stringify()` and `.html()` or `.text()`, which would remove the `"` at beginning and end of result of `JSON.stringify()`, leading to current Question; as `JSON.parse()` is expecting `"{"test":"<a href=\"http://cnn.com\">CNN</a> Hello"}"`, not `{"test":"<a href=\"http://cnn.com\">CNN</a> Hello"}`. One possible solution would be to set the `JSON` at `HTMLElement.dataset`, then use `JSON.parse`, `JSON.stringify()`.

Comment: @squint  _"A data- attribute would be better."_ Agree. Was typing the same suggestion as you were.

Comment: @guest271314: It's not an object literal. That would be in a JS program. It's just text in the document in the format of JSON data.

Comment: `JSON.parse` doesn't expect outer quotes. You're confusing syntax with data. JavaScript programs use outer quotes as *syntax* to create text *data*. The text *data* doesn't get the outer quotes, so `JSON.parse` doesn't get them. It just gets the data.

Comment: ...so when you do this in a JS program: `JSON.parse('{"foo": "bar"}')`, the outer single quotes are just telling the JS program to create some text data, but the actual text data is just what is between the quotes: `{"foo": "bar"}`. That's why if you do `var xyz = "abc";`, the first character of the `xyz` string is `a` not `"`.

Comment: @squint _"JSON.parse doesn't expect outer quotes."_ ? `JSON.parse()` expects a `javascript` object literal?

Comment: @guest271314: It expects text data. Quotation marks in a JS program are *syntax used to denote* text data. The text data itself doesn't have the outer quotes.

Comment: @squint Again, how did the string `{"test":"<a href=\"http://cnn.com\">CNN</a> Hello"}` wind up as `html` of `<span>` ?

Comment: @guest271314: Because just like any other text in the document, the server put it there. It's just text after all.

Comment: @squint Are you stating that the entire `document` was returned as `JSON`?

Comment: @guest271314: No, I'm just saying that the text within that particular span is formatted as JSON data. But the formatting gets screwed up when the HTML is parsed into the DOM. I'll make a jsbin example in a moment.

Comment: @squint _"But the formatting gets screwed up when the HTML is parsed into the DOM"_ Yes, agree. How else can the `<a>` element be rendered? It is not a string, but an element at that point. Where `JSON` is string, not `html` `<a>` element

Comment: So [here's a demo](http://jsbin.com/yubiqasola/1/edit?js,output). Notice there are no quotation marks around the JSON data in the HTML. But it parses, because the string itself is valid JSON. Doing the same thing with the JSON directly in the JS program requires quotes because *all* strings *defined* in a JS program require quotes.

Comment: ...I think the OP was hoping the `.html()` would provide the original HTML markup. Lots of people don't realize that the original HTML is gone after it reaches the browser.

Comment: I have to go. Best of luck!

Comment: @squint- I tried your plunkr basically with getbyid as well as escaping the content on the server and it seems to be working. Will do final test tomorrow. Weird that get by id changes it all

Answer (score 1):

```js
function parse() {
  var span = document.querySelector('span');
  console.log(JSON.parse(span.textContent));
}
```

```html
<span id="content">{"test" : "&lt;a href=\"http://cnn.com\"&gt;CNN&lt;/a&gt; Hello"}</span>
<button onclick="parse()">parse</button>
```

The content inside your span

```
<span id="content">{"test" : "<a href="http://cnn.com">CNN</a> Hello"}</span>
```

should be escaped

```
<span id="content">{"test" : "&lt;a href=\"http://cnn.com\"&gt;CNN&lt;/a&gt; Hello"}</span>
```