# Another way to achieve Object.Assign() in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
Object.assign(home, action.home.fields);
```

I'm assigning `action.home.fields` to my `home` object. Found out that the `Object.assign` isn't supported in IE.

What's the equivalent to what I'm doing that's support in IE?

I read the `spread operator`? So would:

`home = {...home, ...action.home.fields};`

work?

I did check the support on that, wasn't support massively either.

Comment: Just use one of the many ES6 polyfills?

Comment: There's a polyfill in the MDN documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the not-so-official polyfill for `Object.assign()`:

```
if (typeof Object.assign != 'function') {
  (function () {
    Object.assign = function (target) {
      'use strict';
      // We must check against these specific cases.
      if (target === undefined || target === null) {
        throw new TypeError('Cannot convert undefined or null to object');
      }

      var output = Object(target);
      for (var index = 1; index < arguments.length; index++) {
        var source = arguments[index];
        if (source !== undefined && source !== null) {
          for (var nextKey in source) {
            if (source.hasOwnProperty(nextKey)) {
              output[nextKey] = source[nextKey];
            }
          }
        }
      }
      return output;
    };
  })();
}
```

Taken from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

Comment: Not "official," no. Just MDN, a collaboratively-edited resource which is really good, but still subject to error.

Comment: This may not be a de jure standard but as a de facto standard it is pretty well regarded, so from my low vantage point it's as "official" as I can tell :)

Comment: :-) "Well-regarded" and "official" are very, very different things. I remember when MDN had a Truly Amazingly Wrong polyfill for `Array#forEach` (yes, this was a long time ago).

Comment: LOL for "not-so-official" :-)

Comment: @pid See [Is it possible to display an .html document , or .html fragment at CSS content?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36072936/is-it-possible-to-display-an-html-document-or-html-fragment-at-css-content)

Comment: Ok, I admit it, I gave MDN much more credit. You showed me it's not that reliable but I'd still take anytime their code above mine (I'm not that good). I fixed my text.

Comment: https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/blob/master/modules/_object-assign.js --- this might be slightly more trustworthy.

Comment: Someone (deleted their comment which may not be a good sign lol) suggested this polyfill https://github.com/sindresorhus/object-assign I take it, it would be safer/better to edit the above code rather then using a polyfill library?

Comment: @SmurfEkko `core-js` is what trusted by babel.

Comment: @SmurfEkko Try the polyfill, if it works I wouldn't doubt it too much. It's as good as it gets on a browser. If you're on node.js or similar environment you can take a look at zerkms's link, too.

Comment: @pid  Note, the documentation has since been updated https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content$compare?to=1058598&from=1031458

Comment: @guest271314 I starred your question as a preferred, it's a perfect counter-example for my "official" stance :) Thanks for correcting me.