# Content of after in css, how to split text into two styles

Tags: css

I have following code:

```
.button { 
   &[aria-label*='first']::after { content: 'some text'; } 
}
```

It checks if button has aria-label and if it is 'first', it will append 'some text'. I would like to style 'some text' with colors , but 'some' to have black color, and 'text' to have red color. Is that possible and how?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS content property: is it possible to insert HTML instead of Text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4505093/css-content-property-is-it-possible-to-insert-html-instead-of-text)

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan No.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Thank you for that reasoned argument for why this is not a duplicate.

Comment: Why not just use `:before` and `:after`? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/owpZoX

Comment: You could split the text content into `::before` and `::after`

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Sorry mate, see my answer for why it is not a duplicate.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan This is not about why can't HTML content be included. But this is totally different.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Thanks for not understanding the question clearly. Not your fault though... `:)`

Comment: I did understand the question, and your answer just shows using both after and before to solve this specific issue. My duplicate covers any basis, not just two different styles.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan You are kinda right... Please kindly check my answer's comments too! `:)` Thanks BTW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you can't use HTML content in the pseudo elements, well, as an alternative, you can use both `::after` and `::before` for this case. But please note, there are only those two. So, this is the way you go:

```css
.button[aria-label*='first']::after {
  position: relative;
  content: 'some';
  left: 1em;
  color: #fcc;
}

.button[aria-label*='first']::before {
  position: relative;
  content: 'text';
  left: 6.5em;
  color: #ccf;
}
```

```html
<div class="button" aria-label='first-button'>Hi</div>
```

Better way:

```css
.button[aria-label*='first']::after {
  content: 'some';
  color: #f00;
}

.button[aria-label*='first']::before {
  content: 'text';
  color: #ccf;
}
```

```html
<button class="button" aria-label='first-button'></button>
```

Comment: You actually can use HTML in the `content` property, kind of...here is an answer of mine: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36073310/2827823

Comment: Nice, but I already have 'before' occupied with image  &::before { content: url('../../assets/icon.png'); } , so I tried this it is working, but it replaces my image. Can you tell me how to put both image and this part of the text, and I will accept your answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Vikast Ha! Like I have told you already, you can have only two pseudo elements. In your case, I guess, you gotta follow the trick used by LGSon by his answer. You take the call. I guess it is better that way.